# Listing objects in GCS also lists the directory

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to print the list of objects (files) from my Google bucket but the results also contain the subdirectory; temp/. How do I omit this? Google API Doc doesn't indicate that this should be happening.

My Bucket:

```
gs://my_bucket/temp
```

My Code:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(my_bucket)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix="temp/", delimiter='/')

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Results:

```
temp/
temp/2019-02-01_file1.csv
temp/2019-02-01_file2.csv
temp/2019-02-01_file3.csv
temp/2019-02-01_file4.csv
```

Comment: Maybe eliminate any entries that end with "/"?

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach is the one you desire:

If you want to avoid working over the "subfolder" blob, the fastest way to do it is to directly ignore the "subfolder" blob whenever you are iterating over the blobs.

Here's your code with some minor tweaks i have provided. Also, in case you don't want the "temp/" to show when you are listing them i have used the method "replace" similar to Russel H's answer.

```
from google.cloud import storage

my_prefix = "temp/"
my_bucket = "my_bucket_name"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(my_bucket)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix = my_prefix, delimiter = '/')

for blob in blobs:
    if(blob.name != my_prefix): # ignoring the subfolder itself 
        print(" Displaying " + blob.name.replace(my_prefix, "")) # if you only want to display the name of the blob
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this command below:
I just edited the sample script from the GCS [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python)

```
import argparse
import datetime
import pprint

# [START storage_upload_file]
from google.cloud import storage

def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter=None):
   """Lists all the blobs in the bucket that begin with the prefix.
   This can be used to list all blobs in a "folder", e.g. "public/".
   The delimiter argument can be used to restrict the results to only the
   "files" in the given "folder". Without the delimiter, the entire tree under
   the prefix is returned. For example, given these blobs:
       /a/1.txt
       /a/b/2.txt
   If you just specify prefix = '/a', you'll get back:
       /a/1.txt
       /a/b/2.txt
   However, if you specify prefix='/a' and delimiter='/', you'll get back:
       /a/1.txt
   """
   storage_client = storage.Client()
   bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

   blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)

   print('Blobs:')
   for blob in blobs:
       print(blob.name.replace(prefix, ""))

   if delimiter:
       print('Prefixes:')
       for prefix in blobs.prefixes:
           print(prefix)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   list_blobs_with_prefix('[your bucket name]', [prefix]')
```